# PHP adding 10 days to post then have a day count down before the next 'renew' is allowed

Tags: php

I want to let the user renew a post after 10 days since posted and have a count down of how many days left before they can click renew.

My attempt failed, could someone help me with this please?

```
$date = new DateTime($date);
$finish = new DateTime();
$difference = $finish - $date;
if ($date->diff($finish)->days > 10) {  //if the post is over 10 days old
  echo 'Renew now';
}else{
  echo 'Renew in '.$difference.' days</font>';
}
```

Comment: Please define "failed"?

Comment: "(of an undertaking or a relationship) not achieving its end or not lasting; unsuccessful.
"a failed coup attempt"
2.
(of a mechanism) not functioning properly; broken-down.
"an aircraft with a failed engine""

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime($date);
$finish = new DateTime();
$difference = $date->diff($finish);
$difference =$difference->format('%R%a');
if ($difference > 10) {  //if the post is over 10 days old
  echo 'Renew now';
}else{
  echo 'Renew in '.$difference.' days</font>';
}
?>
```

Comment: almost what I want. I want it to show how many days left before you can click renew, and once you click renew, it should reset back to 10 days count down for that post.

Comment: then you need save the current date into a Data Base by each user and load that date in the var $date

Comment: that is what i am doing. $date is from the database from when the post was created

Comment: any idea how to fix that?

Comment: $difference =$difference->format('%R%a'); give you how many days left, and on renew you need update the date on the DB and reset $date

Comment: i am doing this with mysql_query("UPDATE `posts` SET `date`=NOW() WHERE `id` = '" . $_GET['renew_id'] . "' LIMIT 1"); can you tell me how to get it to count down 10 days as soon as you renew the post?